# How to pick a telescope?

Tags: telescope

I am trying to find a started telescope for my high school sister and my goals are to have awesome pictures and to let her explore her interest in the stars!

They live in a clear night sky area so Im looking for the best bang for my buck.

Right now I have picked out 3 telescopes, 2 reflectors and 1 Refractor. What qualities should one look for?

How do I compare telescopes to judge which will work best with a camera and is easy to learn?

What matters most for these conditions? Aperture, Focal Length, or the Focal Ratio?

What type of telescope would be best in terms of my goals?

Comment: See https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/14068/telescope-choice?rq=1 https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/33412/what-kind-of-telescope-should-i-get-my-husband?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/33633/a-budgeted-telescope-around-150?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/17846/suggestions-for-a-beginner-friendly-telescope?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A good telescope for the viewing of Nebulae, Stars and Planets](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/2193/a-good-telescope-for-the-viewing-of-nebulae-stars-and-planets)

Comment: You've left out tracking vs. non-tracking, portability, cost,...

Comment: So my choice is between: 
1) Reflector Type Aperture: 127mm(5. 0"). focal length: 1000mm. Focal Ratio: f/7. 9.
2) Reflector Type Aperture: 130mm(5. 1"). Focal Length: 650mm. Focal Ratio: f/5. 0. 
3) Refractor Type 80mm Astronomical Telescope: 400mm focal length